# Filtering male and female results searchview with recylerview android

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a recylerview with searchview in one of my tabs which contains peoples gender. When I use the searchview to filter male, the female results also show up, this is because female contains male, I have written this but it doesn't seem to work and I have try searching online but haven't anything useful.

```
if (gender.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
            if (query.startsWith("male".toLowerCase())){
                filteredModelList.remove(model.gender.startsWith("female".toLowerCase()));

          }
    }
```

What I want to do is, when user search male, I want the female results to not show and simiarly if people search female I don't want the male results to show.

To give you better understading, I have pasted few screen shots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information? For example, what is filteredModelList? It is a result list, any other known class or a custom class? How is it related to the Adapter?

What is query?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the specific case when query equals "male" like this:

```
if(gender.contains(query))
{
    if(query.toLowerCase().equals("male"))
    {
        if(gender.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
        {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        filteredModelList.add(model);
    }
}
```

So only when you type "male" the"female" wont show.

Comment: Hi, this sound about right however when I implement in my code it crashes trying to fix this problem, I will let you know when I find a solution.

Comment: solved!, however, I have another issue, in future I be adding more data to the list for example name of person + gender e.g. John Male | Emma Female, having this I won't be able to use startsWith, is there any other way you can recommened?

Comment: Now up until 'mal' both female and male shows up but when I type 'male' nothing shows up. The list goes empty

Comment: Uhm i think the problem is in the other part of your code. I tried this and when i type 'mal' it goes to the `else` section, and when i type 'male' it goes inside the `if if` part. It should work..

Comment: Strange, I will go through my code again. Did you try yours with a recylerview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100485/discussion-between-drilon-blakqori-and-henry).

Answer (score 0):

> if (gender.contains(" " + query + " "))

Ugly, but quick fix, that will hopefully work. Provide some more code if you want a better solution.